# How to in Python use data in an API to access data from another JSON file?

Tags: python, json, api

I'm in a bit of a pickle with an issue i've got in Python. I have an API online (JSON) containing a list of people, all with separate ID numbers.

I want to take those ID numbers to another JSON file with separate data (about their housing situation) and print out their housing details and names together.

To give you an idea, here is an example of the JSON file with people (example_1.json):

```
{"value":[{
      "name": "Alan Smith",
       "id" : "ibcd23"},
       {"name": "Paul Flack",
       "id" : "aasd201"}]
```

and here an example of the second json file (example_2.json) with housing status:

```
{"value":[{
  "id": "ibcd23",
  "housing": "apartment"},
  {"id": "aasd201",
  "housing": "villa"}]}
```

How would you approach this? I only came as far as to identify the ID values:

```
import json

with open("example_1.json") as input_file:
    data = json.load(input_file)

for i in data["value"]:
    x = i["Id"]
```

Thanks in advance for any help

B.t.w. I didn't include the actual JSON files/API link as it is huge and contains far more data then just "name" and "id" so I thought it might overcomplicate the issue.

EDIT:
So here is the solution thanks to TomNash:

```
for person in people["value"]:
    for status in housing_status["value"]:
        if status['id'] == person['id']:
            print(status['housing']+ " " + person['name'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON isn't set up the best, but this should work:

```py
example_1 = json.dumps({"value":[{
      "name": "Alan Smith",
       "id" : "ibcd23"},
       {"name": "Paul Flack",
       "id" : "aasd201"}]})
example_2 = json.dumps({"value":[{
  "id": "ibcd23",
  "housing": "apartment"},
  {"id": "aasd201",
  "housing": "villa"}]})

people = json.loads(example_1)
housing_status = json.loads(example_2)

{person['name']:status['housing']
 for person in people["value"]
 for status in housing_status["value"]
 if status['id'] == person['id']}
```